# redirect url/ to url/test using ingress

Tags: nginx, ingress, ingress-nginx

I'm running an application on kubernetes, when i use this url: https://myapp.test.com/ it redirects me to ressource not found (problem in the application).
what i need now is to avoid this page by redirecting the url/ to url/test where i have the home page of the application.
Is this possible using Ingress?
If you can show me please an example of a configuration that does this redirection.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add an annotation nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /test as per the documentation kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#app-root

Quoted from the doc and adapted to your exemple, your ingress yaml should look like this (adapt the target service and port):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /test
  name: myapp
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: myapp.test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: http-svc
            port: 
              number: 80
```